# What would happen if exactly one additional anion is added to the universe without also adding the corresponding opposite charged cation?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, astrophysics

What would hypothetically happen if, for example, exactly 1 Cl- were added to the entire universe? I study chemistry and it is always the case that we keep the charges on the left and right in reactions and have to balance them accordingly. I used to wonder what would happen to ions that change into the gaseous state in an evaporating solution, for example. When they bind with oxygen, this oxide must still be charged, so there must be a suitable differently charged ion floating around somewhere with which it can bind, if not it would be almost an infinite chain reaction because even if this ion (cation) binds with the anion of another salt, the new cation of this salt would have to find a new anion and so on. So is it really a universal principle because in the big bang the total charge was really *exactly* neutral?

Comment: It is not at all a certainty that the universe has a net zero charge.

Comment: GR is unstable upon charge perturbations. Adding a single electron to a Schwarzschild solution converts it to a Reissner–Nordström black hole, creates a Cauchy horizon and other potential effects like closed time loops, null and timelike singularities, plus potentially opens passes to other universes. The Big Band was a spacelike singularity meaning it was a moment in time. Adding an unbalanced charge to the universe may make the Big Bang singularity timelike meaning existing until now and unpredictably spitting out matter in arbitrary amounts. It would be a very different universe.

Answer (score 5):

The universe would implode from the charge imbalance.

Kidding – in reality I don't see how anything would happen. There are plenty of free, unbalanced charges flying through space. E.g. trillions of free protons are being released by the Sun every second. One more will not change anything. If instead you started talking about a significant charge imbalance (like a 51:49 ratio in favor of negative charges) globally across all regions of the universe, that would point to something in the nature of the electromagnetic interaction that deviates from theory and everything we see. But even if a cloud of negative charged matter the size of a galaxy suddenly "appeared" spontaneously, although it would produce some extremely strong forces and fields in its neighborhood, it would not "unbalance" the universe overall.  The universe does not keep a talley of overall charge. Regions and objects can only interact limited by the speed of light and future light cones, so most of the universe would not notice anything in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you cannot add any *net* charge to the Universe, because electric charge is conserved.

However, you can ask about a Universe where the total charge is some non-zero number. Then, I think so long as that number is "small," the Universe will look like the Universe we live in, which is apparently electrically neutral (as far as we can tell). For a large charge imbalance, you would start to see attraction between positive and negative charges on large, astrophysical scales in the history of the Universe. This article describes some observational tests that support the idea that our Universe is close to electrically neutral: https://bigthink.com/starts-with-a-bang/universe-neutral